# Problem with Transforming and Augmenting images in pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, image-augmentation

I want to apply augmentation methods to my image. For this, I chose codes from this website https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png')

augmentation = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torchvision.transforms.RandomGrayscale(.5), 
    torchvision.transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(.5)
)
cv.imwrite('test.png', augmentation)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I hope someone can help me here. Thank You

Comment: What is the error? Secondly, try using `cv2` instead of just **cv**

Comment: `error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'`

Comment: What do you expect `cv.imwrite('test.png', augmentation)` exactly? Please read your code again, this doesn't make any sense, you are trying to write a function as an image.

Comment: @Deshwal no. use `import cv2 as cv`